# Proving that $\frac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt} - \frac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt} = k_{\nabla}(\frac{d\gamma}{ds}, \frac{d\gamma}{dt})(u)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature

I am currently trying to make Exercise 20 of these [lecture notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_AK0HGxgYXJas46SWFxTmbNR0eCCTH2/view).
It should be a very simple exercise, but I am swamped due to the amount of bookkeeping. I fear I am missing a very simple nuance that makes it impossible for me to solve this problem. I'll briefly mention the exercise below with the relevant notes from the lecture notes.

### The Exercise

> **Exercise 20.** Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle equipped with the connection $\nabla$. Let $\gamma = \gamma(t,s) \colon I_1 \times I_2 \to M$ be a smooth map defined on the product of two intervals $I_1, I_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $u = u(t,s) \colon I_1 \times I_2 \to E$ a smooth covering. Show that
> $$
> \frac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt} - \frac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt} = k_\nabla \left( \frac{d\gamma}{ds}, \frac{d\gamma}{dt} \right)(u),
> $$
> where $k_\nabla$ in the induced curvature.

### Clarifying the notation

Let me elucidate the notation $\frac\nabla{dt}$ and $\frac\nabla{ds}$.
If $\gamma \colon I \to M$ is a path, then we can use sections $s \in \Gamma(E)$ to produce smooth coverings $u = s \circ \gamma \colon I \to E$.  This implies that the notation
$$
\nabla_{\dot \gamma}(s)(\gamma(t)) 
$$
makes sense as you can view $\dot \gamma$ as a sort of vector field. We denote this as
$$
\frac{\nabla(s \circ \gamma)}{dt}.
$$
So more generally, we can define the operator $\frac{\nabla}{dt}$ to define a new path for smooth coverings of $\gamma$
$$
\frac{\nabla u}{dt} \colon I \to E.
$$
Locally with respect to a frame $e = (e_j)_j$, we may write $u(t) = \sum_j u^je_j(\gamma(t))$. Then using formula (1.18) from these lecture notes, one may write the $i$'th component of $\frac{\nabla u}{dt}$ with respect to this frame as
$$
\left( \frac{\nabla u}{dt} \right)^i = \frac{d u^i}{dt}(t) + \sum_j(t) \omega^i_j(\dot \gamma(t)).
$$
Here $\omega = (\omega^i_j)$ represents the connection matrix, representing the one-forms that you obtain from the equation $\nabla_X(e_j) = \sum_i \omega_i^j(X) e_i$.

### My strategy, my work and what I find hard

For this exercise I had the following strategy in mind. I was planning to use the last formula twice:  twice to calculate $\frac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt}$ and twice to calculate $\frac{\nabla^2 u}{dt \, ds}$. From there I hoped it would resemble the local form of the curvature.

What I find hard is the following:

- By applying that formula, you get **a lot** of terms, and I guess that my bookkeeping skills can't keep up at the moment. Maybe I am just going about it the wrong way. Here is [my work](https://pdfhost.io/v/HP7D1.1xV_Differential_Geometry_MSc_Lecture_3pdf.pdf) until now.
- I also found it hard to properly express the local form of the curvature in terms of the connection: $k = d \omega + \omega \wedge \omega$, where $(\omega \wedge \omega)^i_j = \sum_k \omega^i_k \wedge \omega^k_j$ is the local connection matrix. I was never able to prove this (maybe I should open a separate thread for this, but so be it).

So am I missing an important nuance? Is this the right strategy? It this just really a matter of bookkeeping and am I just messing up?

Thanks in advance for the feedback!

Comment: I changed $\dfrac{\nabla^2 u}{ds dt}$ to $\dfrac{\nabla^2 u}{ds \, dt}$ $\vphantom{\frac{}{\displaystyle\sum}}$and in multiple instances I changed $ds dt,$ coded as `ds dt`, to $ds \, dt,$ coded as `ds \, dt`. Similarly one writes $f(x)\,dx$ rather than $f(x) dx$ and $f(x_i)\,\Delta x$ rather than $f(x_i) \Delta x,$ etc.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for the LaTeX Feedback! Always appreciated :)

Comment: I'm glad it helps. $\qquad$

Comment: One way that would be nice, have you tried using proposition 1.24's expression for the curvature with $X = \frac{d \gamma}{dt}, Y = \frac{d \gamma}{ds}$ and then verifying that $[X,Y] = 0$?

Comment: I concur with @TheoDiamantakis's suggestion!

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis Thank you a lot for the suggestion, I will try it out asap and I'll report back! :)