# Confusion about pushforwards of Lie Brackets

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, pushforward

This is a very simple example that's bugging me, there's a basic gap in my understanding.

Let $\gamma : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow M$ be a curve, show that $[\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial s}] = 0$.

I can immediately solve it using the fact that $[\gamma_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}), \gamma_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial s})] = \gamma_*[\frac{\partial }{\partial s},\frac{\partial }{\partial s}]$, and the coordinate vector fields vanish in the bracket, but if I try and do things the long way round I start getting quite muddled.

If I try to do things in coordinates, I end up having to calculate stuff like $X(\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s})$ for $X = \left.\frac{\partial \gamma^j}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right|_{\gamma(t)}$, but $\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s}$ is a function of $t$ and $s$, so how can it make sense to differentiate it with the $x^i$ coordinates on $M$?

I suspect this has something to do with pullback bundles, indeed, if you have access to a connection then I "feel compelled" to want to write something like $X(\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s}) = \nabla_X(\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s})   = \gamma^*\nabla_\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s}) = \frac{\partial^2 \gamma^i}{\partial t\partial s}$, but this is wrong (I'm not getting any $\frac{\partial \gamma^j}{\partial t}$ terms, and I shouldn't have to invoke a connection anyway).

Any explanation appreciated.

Following Andreas Cap's answer, I have wish to understand when this works. If $\gamma(s,t) = (x(s,t), y(s,t))$ is a diffeomorphism of $2$ dimensional manifolds, then it makes sense to pushforward the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. I can say

$\gamma_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}) = \left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{\gamma(s,t)} + \left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{\gamma(s,t)}$

$\gamma_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}) = \left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{\gamma(s,t)} + \left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right|_{\gamma(s,t)}$

If I want to try and take the Lie bracket then I have $$\left[\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right. + \left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right., \left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right. + \left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(s,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right]$$

This is the same problem, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}(s,t)$ are functions of $s,t$ but we must differentiate them with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in this bracket.

Edit: I was being foolish, you are supposed to use $\gamma$ to write the reconcile the coordinates using the fact its a diffeomorphism, so the calculation indeed works when the pushforwards are well defined.

Comment: From what you've written, is $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial s}$ the vector field given in coordinates by $\frac{\partial \gamma^i}{\partial s}(t_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\vert_{\gamma(t_0)}$?

Comment: That would be what I call $X$, when we do the Lie bracket I take $X$(the components of $Y$), which is just the partial derivative and not a vector field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no well defined operation of push forward of vector fields along smooth maps. Indeed, the "vector fields" that you are trying to use are certainly only defined on the image of $\gamma$. Even there, they may not be well defined if $\gamma$ is not injective. So it is not obvious how the initial question makes sense, the question being what the Lie bracket should be.

The expressions $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial s}$ certainly make sense as "vector fields along $\gamma$, i.e. as maps $\xi:[0,1]^2\to TM$ such that $p\circ\xi=\gamma$. (These can be viewed as sections of the pullback bundle $\gamma^*TM$ over $[0,1]^2$ but I don't think that there is a Lie bracket in this seeting.

A way to make sense of the original question is the setting of $\gamma$-related vector fields. This means that you suppose that there are vector fields $\xi$ and $\eta$ on $M$ such that $\xi\circ \gamma=T\gamma\circ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$,  and similarly for $\eta$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$. (This just mean that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are vector fields whose restriction to the image of $\gamma$ gives the objects you were trying to construct. Such fields will not exist in general, they certainly do if e.g. $\gamma$ is an embedding.) Then there is a general result saying that the brackets of $\gamma$-related vector fields are $\gamma$-related, which then shows that $[\xi,\eta]$ vanishes on the image of $\gamma$.

Comment: I see! I forgot about that, so since curves aren't diffeomorphisms, this wont really make sense and that's why it doesn't work? What if $\gamma$ was an invertible map to $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, how would I do the calculation? For context the question was inspired by this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002259/proving-that-frac-nabla2-uds-dt-frac-nabla2-uds-dt-k-na?noredirect=1#comment8260789_4002259

Comment: also, can you explain why there is no Lie bracket on the pullback bundle? Why not, if I have vector fields I can bracket them no?

Comment: Sections of the pullback bundle are not vector fields, and you can certainly not use such sections to differentiate functions.. Existence of the Lie bracket of vector fields is a very surprising fact (there are very few operations that are natural under local diffeomorphisms), so asking there is no Lie bracket goes in the wrong direction. Concerning the first comment, in case of a diffeomorphism, there is a well defined push-forward, which is compatible with the Lie bracket, so your original argument works. The question you link to deals with pullback connections (no brackets there).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, 1 last question that I have added to the original question as an edit, I am trying to make this work when $\gamma$ is a diffeomorphism but am still running in the same problem.

Comment: @AndreasCap, I deleted what I now understand was a silly answer. Just wanted to thank you for your comments. I think I once understood this more clearly.

The Lie bracket is the Lie derivative of two vector fields and is in a sense dual to the exterior derivative of a $1$-form, which is the Lie derivative of the $1$-form. What I forgot: You can always pull back the exterior derivative but not push forward the Lie bracket (except in special circumstances).

Comment: @Deane no problem, you are welcome. These are subtle issues, For example the Lie derivative is natural only as an operator depending on two arguements, while the exterior derivative is natural as a linear operator (although in the end this boils down  to the same property in the case of one-forms).

Comment: @AndreasCap, this started me thinking about a coordinate-free proof that exterior differentiation commutes with pullback. It's not straightforward, because the Lie bracket does not commute with pushforward. You do indeed need to use the fact that both $f^*(d\omega)$ and $d(f^*\omega)$ are tensors and play games with the tangent vectors. This is indeed very subtle.

Answer (score 1):

The right setting is indeed the pullback of the tangent bundle of $M$. Here's a brief summary.

If you have a map $\Phi: N \rightarrow M$, you can pull back the tangent bundle $T = T_*M$ to a bundle $T^\Phi$ over $N$. Given a connection $\nabla$ on $T_*M$, you can pull that back to a connection $\nabla^\Phi$ on $T^\Phi$. Observe that if $X$ is a tangent vector field on $N$, then $\Phi_*X$ is a section of $T^\Phi$. Therefore, given vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $N$, $\nabla_X\Phi_*Y$ is a section of $T^\Phi$.

Now suppose the connection $\nabla$ is torsion-free. Then there is the following formula for the pushforward of the Lie bracket:
$$
\Phi_*[X,Y] = \nabla^\Phi_X\Phi_*Y - \nabla^\Phi_Y\Phi_*X
$$

This is the appropriate abstract setting for the standard derivation of the Jacobi equation for Jacobi fields on a Riemannian manifold.

I've written up the details here: [https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/PullbackConnection.pdf](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Eyangd/papers/PullbackConnection.pdf)

Comment: @AndreasCap, I'd be grateful if you would be able to take a look and see if it looks correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So we don't need the super strong requirement of a diffeomorphism and can get away with just an immersion? In the case $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism does this agree with the Lie bracket defined by just pushing forward $X,Y$ by $\Phi_*\left(X_{\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)}\right)$ and taking their bracket? I suppose $\nabla$ should be Levi Civita, and when we have no metric we are stuck with diffeomorphisms only?

Comment: My formula does not require an immersion, just a smooth map. If the map is an embedding, then the image of $\Phi$ is a submanifold, and my formula does imply $[\Phi_*X,\Phi_*Y] = \Phi_*[X,Y]$. Even the standard formula $[X,Y] = \nabla_XY - \nabla_YX$ requires that the connection be torsion-free. But no metric is needed, so the connection need not be a Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: I see. Embedding or immersion for the equivalence? Your typed notes say immersion is the required condition on page 2.

Comment: If you want the formula $[\Phi_*X,\Phi_*Y]$ for a sufficiently small neighborhood of a point, an immersion is enough. If you want it to hold on the entire domain, then you need an embedding, because if the map is not 1-1, the image is not a vector field where the inverse image is more than one point. My formula works for all smooth maps. This is needed when studying Jacobi fields, because the map is often not 1-1.

Comment: Another sufficient assumption for $[\Phi_*X,\Phi_*Y] = \Phi_*[X,Y]$ to make sense and holds, without assuming the map to be an embeddingthat works for a maps, without assuming the map to be an embedding, is if the vector fields are $\Phi$-related. This is mentioned in @AndreasCap's answer. This, I believe, is not sufficient for studying Jacobi fields.